# External Link using full screen in Phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, inappbrowser

im trying to open an external link to facebook within my iOS Phonegap app without it taking over the whole page. Ideally I want it in sort of an iFrame where the navigation would remain.

At the moment I have a share button that opens up Facebook using the in app browser. Here is the code:

```
    function shareonfb()
    {
        photoid = sessionStorage.PhotoId;
        filename = sessionStorage.PhotoFilename;

        postUrl  = "http://mysitelink.com/page.php?photoid="+photoid;

        imageUrl = "http://mysitelink.com/pages/"+filename;

        var sSiteUrl="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&u="+postUrl; 

        var ref = window.open(sSiteUrl, '_self', 'location=yes,');

    }

<input id="btnshare" type="button" value="Share" data-icon="arrow-r"
                data-inline="true" onclick="javascript:{shareonfb();};" />
```

My problem is Facebook takes over, with no way of returning to the app. Any ideas of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup an exit event to listen for a window.close coming from the inapp browser..

These are the events from phonegap doco

- loadstart - event fired when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL
- loadstop - event fired when the InAppBrowser finished loading a URL
- loaderror - event fired when the InAppBrowser encounters an error loading a URL
- ** exit - event fired when the InAppBrowser window is closed**

So something like .

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { ref.close(); });
```

should do the trick.